# I can't access tf.Dataset when insert statement including 'from transformers' such as "from transformers import glue_processors"

Tags: python, tensorflow

when run the following code(run_tf_glue_Test.py) from command prompt of Win10 (python run_tf_glue_Test.py), the code stops without error after working some minutes. The information before
'for line in datasets:' statement showed in the console therefore I assume the tf.Dataset generated.

This code was modified and removed most of the main functions in the original run_tf_glue.py(locates in trnsformers/eamaples/text-clasification/ downloaded by 'git clone [https://github.com/huggingface/transformers'](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers%27) then installed by pip) to simplify and clarify the reason for this problem. Modification against the original code was made to feed text file into  glue_convert_examples_to_features functions after converting into tf.Dataset with dictionary format.

This problem occurs in the module generating tf.Datase but the same code works fine in colaboratory.

Do I miss something in my local environment?

python environment:3.7.6

```
# coding=utf-8
""" Fine-tuning the library models for sequence classification."""


import logging,sys
import os
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from enum import Enum
from typing import Dict, Optional

import numpy as np,csv
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from transformers import glue_processors


def gen_dataset(subf):
    print('** in**')
    #tf.enable_eager_execution()
    logging.info('version(%s)',tf.__version__)
    categories = ['0', '1'] 
    category_to_id = {
        category: index for index, category in enumerate(categories)
    }
    origin='c:/tools/python37/transformers/'+subf+'.tsv'
    origin=origin.replace('validation','dev')
    logging.info('*** origin(%s)',origin)
    with open(origin,'r',encoding='utf-8') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin,delimiter='\t')
        
        rows = [{
            'idx': index,
            'sentence': row[0],
            'label': category_to_id[row[1]],
        } for index, row in enumerate(reader) if row[1] in categories]
    datasets = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: rows,{'idx': tf.int64, 'sentence': tf.string, 'label': tf.int64}
    )
    logging.info('** records(%d) type(%s)**',len(rows),type(datasets))
    for line in datasets:
        logging.info('*** line(%s)',line)
        print('** lines:',line)
        sys.exit(7)
    return(datasets,len(rows))

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(
        format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s -   %(message)s",
        datefmt="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",
        level=logging.INFO,
    )

    gen_dataset('data/train')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was caused by GPU usage therefore insert 'os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"' after 'import os' statement to specify to use cpu only then the problem goes away.

Sorry for stealing your time.